# how to check if a number is a power of base b?

Tags: python, logarithm

In python, how can you check if a number n is an exact power of base b?

Note: it needs to be generalized to any base which is given as a parameter.

Here is what I got:

Assume n and base are integers > 0.

```
import math
def is_power(n,base):
    return math.log(n,base) == base**n
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking if the math.log(n, base) is *any* integer?

Comment: Why would `math.log(n,base)` ever equal `base**n`? 128 is a power of 2, but `2**128` is definitely not `7`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, assuming you have a specific logarithm operator (many languages provide logarithms to base `10` or base `e` only), `logab` can be calculated as `logxb / logxa` (where `x` is obviously a base that your language provides).

Python goes one better since it can work out the logarithm for an *arbitrary* base without that tricky equality above.

So one way or another, you have a way to get logarithm to a specific base. From there, if the log of `b` in base `a` is an integer<sup>(note 1)</sup>, then `b` is a power of `a`.

So I'd start with the following code, now with added edge-case detection:

```
# Don't even think about using this for negative powers :-)

def isPower (num, base):
    if base in {0, 1}:
        return num == base
    power = int (math.log (num, base) + 0.5)
    return base ** power == num
```

See for example the following complete program which shows this in action:

```
import math

def isPower (num, base):
    if base in {0, 1}:
        return num == base
    power = int (math.log (num, base) + 0.5)
    return base ** power == num

print isPower (127,2)       # false
print isPower (128,2)       # true
print isPower (129,2)       # false
print

print isPower (26,3)        # false
print isPower (27,3)        # true
print isPower (28,3)        # false
print isPower (3**10,3)     # true
print isPower (3**129,3)    # true
print

print isPower (5,5)         # true
print isPower (1,1)         # true
print isPower (10,1)        # false
```

---

If you're the sort that's worried about floating point operations, you *can* do it with repeated multiplications but you should test the performance of such a solution since it's likely to be substantially slower in software than it is in hardware. That won't matter greatly for things like `isPower(128,2)` but it may become a concern for `isPower(verybignum,2)`.

For a non-floating point variant of the above code:

```
def isPower (num, base):
    if base in {0, 1}:
        return num == base
    testnum = base
    while testnum < num:
        testnum = testnum * base
    return testnum == num
```

But make sure it's tested against your largest number and smallest base to ensure you don't get any performance shocks.

---

<sup>(Note 1)</sup> Keep in mind here the possibility that floating point imprecision may mean it's not *exactly* an integer. You may well have to use a "close enough" comparison.

Comment: 1) `math.exp` only takes 1 argument. If you fix that, then 2) You'll get the wrong answer for `isPower(3**10, 3)`.

Comment: Fails for boundary cases like `isPower(1, 1)`

Comment: @Robᵩ, `exp` was the wrong function, it's been changed into `pow`.

Comment: @wim, that's why I said "start with", I'll update the code to fix that edge case.

Comment: and 3**10 isn't even a very big number (59049)

Comment: That's solved by using round instead of int to take care of things like introduced FP inaccuracy.

Comment: Now it fails for `isPower(3**129, 3)`

Comment: -1 just avoid FP altogether, there is no need to introduce these complications.

Comment: @wim, that's another possibility but it introduced other problems such as `isPower(big_honkin_number,2)` which is likely to be substantially slower. For things like `ispower(128,2)`, that probably won't matter but it may become a concern as the number becomes large - this is, of course, not something that's been specified in the question specifically,.

Answer (score 5):

A very simple solution could go like this:

```
def ispower(n, base): 

    if n == base:
        return True

    if base == 1:
        return False

    temp = base

    while (temp <= n):
        if temp == n:
            return True
        temp *= base

    return False
```

Result:

```
>>> ispower(32, 2)
True
>>> ispower(81, 3)
True
>>> ispower(625, 5)
True
>>> ispower(50, 5)
False
>>> ispower(32, 4)
False
>>> ispower(2,1)
False
>>> ispower(1,1)
True
```

Comment: +1 very good.  you might want to fix the infinite loop case with something like `ispower(2, 1)` though.

Comment: You fixed the infinite loop, but you wrote a bug.  `ispower(2, 1)` should be false.

Comment: You probably want to look at the other edge cases as well. `ispower(1,1)` should be true, as should `ispower(1,0)`. Technically you may also want to handle negative powers but I've just stated my answer does not allow that :-)

Comment: The question stated "Assume n and base are integers > 0".

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. That means you only _need_ to cover `ispower(1,1)`.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I fixed the `ispower(1,1)` case, but would `ispower(1,0)` be certainly true? This would be true if 0 ** 0 = 1, but that's not very clear.

Comment: `0**0 == 1` in python, although perhaps it should have been left undefined.  It's a moot point anyway, given the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def isPower(n, b):
...   return b**int(math.log(n, b)+.5)==n
... 
>>> isPower(128, 2)
True
>>> isPower(129, 2)
False
>>> isPower(3**10, 3)
True
>>> isPower(3**129, 3)
True
>>> isPower(10**500, 10)
True
>>> isPower(10**(10**6), 10)
True
```

---

**EDIT**: This code does fail for `1,1`:

```
>>> isPower(1,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in isPower
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

I'll leave it to the OP to decide if he wants to apply the trivial fix or rewrite his requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a constant-time solution that handles every special case mentioned in the comments so far:

```py
import math

def is_power(a, b, precision=14):
    if a == 1 or a == b:
        return True
    if b in (0, 1):
        return False
    return round(math.log(a, b), precision).is_integer()
```

Behavior for each special case:

| a | b | is_power(a, b) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3^10 | 3 | [True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352593/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-base-b#comment21688263_15352628) ✔️ |
| 3^129 | 3 | [True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352593/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-base-b#comment21688357_15352628) ✔️ |
| 2 | 1 | [False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352593/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-base-b#comment21688482_15352695) ✔️ |
| 1 | 1 | [True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352593/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-base-b#comment21688759_15352695) ✔️ |
| 1 | 0 | [True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352593/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-base-b#comment21688759_15352695) ✔️ |
| 17^3 | 17 | [True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352593/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-base-b#comment74446871_42320297) ✔️ |

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a nice simple way of doing it (without calling a library) recursively:

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
  if number < base:
    return number == 1
  return is_power_of(number/base, base)
```

Comment: Hi Agahowa, thank you for your time and contribution. What if the `number` variable converts to a non-integer value when divided by `base`?

Answer (score -1):

`>>>(math.log(int(num),int(base))).is_integer()`

This will return a boolean value either true or false. This should work fine. Hope it helps

Comment: Nope, try `(math.log(4913, 17)).is_integer()` for example.

Comment: @EugeneYarmash, let me know what is the difference between the solution I gave and the correction you proposed.
Can you specify scenario in which solution fails or the mistake in the solution.

Comment: Well, your 'solution' apparently doesn't work for the example I posted 1+ year ago. log17(4913) == 3, which **is** an integer.